# how to memorize a value obtained from redux REACTJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to obtain a value from a variable hosted in redux and memorize it, to later compare it with itself and verify if it is different.

I need, for example, to do the following : const value = useSelector(state => state.data.value); (suppose that here the value is 0) now, when value changes, i need to compare it with the value it had previously

Comment: Can you give some more details? When do you want to save it, and when do you want to compare it? Is it from one render of a component to the next render, or a longer period of time? For that matter, is this in a component at all?

Comment: I need, for example, to do the following :

 const value = useSelector(state => state.data.value); (suppose that here the value is 0)

 now, when value changes, i need to compare it with the value it had previously

Comment: So, you want to check what the value was on the previous render, and you don't care about further back in time?

Comment: **Why** do you want to compare it? The answer to this question will probably yield the answer you actually want. I’m thinking what you might want is just a plain old useEffect (which, by definition compares the value with what it was previously), but maybe not. The simplest answer is to just set it in local state, every time it changes, then you have both the current value (from useSelector) and the last value (in local state)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check what the value was on the previous render, you can save it in a ref:

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const value = useSelector(state => state.data.value)
  const prevRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    // Once the render is complete, update the ref's value
    prevRef.current = value;
  });
  // Do something comparing prevRef.current and value 
}
```

If you're doing this a lot you might find it useful to make a custom hook:

```
const usePrevious = (value) => {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.curren;t
}

// used like:
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const value = useSelector(state => state.data.value)
  const prev = usePrevious(value);
  // Do something comparing prev and value.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use selectors(i use 'reselect' library for that), such as:

file: `selectors.js`

```js
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const stateEnvironments = state => state.environments;

export const selectEnvironments = createSelector([stateEnvironments], 
environments => environments.data);
```

so then in your component you can use `mapStateToProps` with `reselect` and `connect`

```js
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

// your component here
const EnvironmentCurrencies = props => {
  const {
    data,
  } = props;

  return (
  <div>
  ...
  </div.
  );
};


const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  data: selectEnvironments,
});

// here you can update your values with actions
// mapDispatchToProps is especially useful for constraining our actions to the connected component.
// You can access these via `this.props`.
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setEnvironment: environment => dispatch(actions.setEnvironment(environment)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Environments);
```

this is not a full working example and the version that you might use, can have a bit different synaxis, but I hope this gives you a kick start. If not, let me know, I'll add more extensive example